# Repeat values Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say I have a numbers sequence:

```
 2 5 7 8 0 0 0
```

And I want the following sequence:

```
2 5 7 8 8 8 8
```

That is: repeat the last number before zeros, This can be accomplished with Linq ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can there be zeros in the middle of the sequence?

Comment: Yes zeros can be in the middle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking, no. But you can write your own:

```
public static class SomeExtension
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> ReplaceDefaultByPreviousNonDefault(this IEnumerable<T> sequence)
    {
        T previous = default(T);

        foreach(var val in squence)
        {
            if(val == default(t)) yield return previous;

            previous = val;

            yield return val;        
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
var numbers = new int[] { 2, 5, 7, 8, 0, 0, 0 };

var result = numbers.ReplaceDefaultByPreviousNonDefault();
```

If you really really really insist on artificially introducing a LinQ method, you could take the above loop and just build it into a select:

```
  var numbers = new int[] { 2, 5, 7, 8, 0, 0, 0 };

  int last = 0;
  var result = numbers.Select(n => n == 0 ? last : last = n);
```

Comment: Well, it's an extension method for `IEnumerable<T>` just like LinQ.

Comment: if solution produces extension method, it doesn't mean, that it uses Linq :)

Comment: It does not use linq. Read the first sentence. You could obviously artificially introduce LinQ, but that would be pointless. Instead, this is something that looks like LinQ and sounds like LinQ. Just as lets say [morelinq](https://morelinq.github.io/).

Comment: @tym32167 Added a bit of "real" LinQ :) I don't think it's as nice as the extension method though.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this with LINQ using the `.Aggregate()` method:

```
int[] numbers = { 2, 5, 7, 8, 0, 0, 0 };

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", numbers
    .Aggregate(new List<int>(), (l, n) =>
        {
            l.Add(n == 0 ? l.Last() : n);
            return l;
        })));
```

I get:

```
2 5 7 8 8 8 8
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer doesn't use LINQ, but achieves the same result.

```
var originalCollection = [ 2, 5, 7, 8, 0, 0, 0 ].ToList();
int removeCount = 0;

while (originalCollection[originalCollection.Count - 1] == 0) {
    removeCount++;
}

originalCollection.RemoveRange( (originalCollection - removeCount - 1), (originalCollection - 1) );

var finalElement = originalCollection[originalCollection.Count - 1];

for (int i = removeCount; i > 0; i--) {
    originalCollection.Add(finalElement)
}
```

Comment: That almost has nothing to do with LINQ. The only place you use LINQ is with `.Count()`. And even then, you should be using the more efficient `.Count` property of `List<T>`.

Comment: Sure, but who cares? It works, and LINQ really isn't needed. I get that when people say they "want to use LINQ/jQuery" their intentions are well-meant, but why not use the vanilla language?

Comment: @NickBull I'd guess the OP cares, since that's what he asked for.

Comment: Because the question was specifically about doing it in LINQ. When people come to this question later via search, they'll find your totally irrelevant answer.

Comment: @DrewKennedy Again, intentions can be well meant! Why does he need to use that over the vanilla language if the vanilla language achieves the functionality?

Comment: Then maybe improve your answer to say something about your answer not being LINQ-y, and why. A code dump isn't very helpful.

Comment: @DrewKennedy Sure, update made. The "dumped" (may I say, lovingly hand-written too) code answers the question - I'd say that's helpful if I asked the question.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution (not a best by performance and without assuming corner cases)

```
var data = new[] {0 ,0 , 2, 5, 7, 8, 0, 0, 0, 7, 7, 7, 9, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0 };
var rezult = data.Select((x,i)=>x == 0 ? data.Take(i).LastOrDefault(z=>z!=0) :x).ToArray();
```